# Where is the space coming from at the bottom of the footer

Tags: html, css

I have this page [here](http://posnation.com/shop_pos/) and if you scroll to the bottom you can see a space at the bottom but for the life of me i cant seem to figure out what is causing it...any ideas..

Comment: Can you please post the pertinent code here or in a JSfiddle?  Without it, this question won't be useful once you fix the issue on your live site.

Answer (score 2):

It's the height specification on `#footer-content-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

as far as I know, the * is more of a hack for IE. Merge these two things together:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
}
```